# How to upload a map style created on Google Cloud Maps to Google MyMaps?

Tags: maps, cloud, mymaps

The styles on Google My Maps are kind of boring so i went out of my way to make my own style, rather stupidly i forgot to check if the styles were transferable which it doesn't appear they are but i am not well versed in either program.

The reason i need this map in google my maps is because the drawing of polygons and lines are essential to the purpose of the map and i really dont want to be bogged down having to do everything in code.

TL;DR - Tried making a map style in google cloud maps to transfer to google my maps and layer everything over it, has not worked because the two google programs don't speak to each other for whatever reason.